# How to store entire response and update it for next rest call using Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Question: How to extract entire restAPI response and modify it with some values and use the updated response for sub-sequent rest call. I am using Jmeter

## Question Scenario:

I have one POST call ex:  "/check1/id1/post"
POST body :

```
{ 
                "test":"rest",
                "check" :{ 
                           "id":1,
                           "name": "xyz"
                         }
             }
```

POST call RESPONSE :

```
{ 
            "test":"rest",
            "check" :{ 
                       "id":1,
                       "name": "xyz"
                       "status":"updated"
                     }
         }
```

=====================================================================

QUESTION: Now, I have to use entire above RESPONSE in next POST Call body as below, BUT, I wanted to update  "id" value as 2 and then need to POST rest call.

REST CALL: ------ >  "/check1/id2/post"
         POST BODY as below : ------->

```
{ 
            "test":"rest",
            "check" :{ 
                       "id":2,
                       "name": "xyz"
                       "status":"updated"
                     }
         }
```

=============================================================

Can anyone please guide on this? , I am clueless about how to solve this issue?, I need to solve this using Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) or [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

Assuming a valid JSON

```
{ 
            "test":"rest",
            "check" :{ 
                       "id":1,
                       "name": "xyz",
                       "status":"updated"
                     }
         }
```

Here are the steps

1. Add a JSR223 preprocessor to the 2nd post request.
2. Add the following code to the preprocessor

   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
   builder.content.check.id = '2'
   vars.put("POSTDATA",builder.toPrettyString())

Above code will update ID value with 2 and stores the JSON in POSTDATA , you can use `${POSTDATA}` to post the JSON FILE

[image]

In my pre processor i'm saving the response using `prev.getResponseData()` , that means this pre processor must included with the sampler right next to the first sampler.

For more information on beanshell Please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Comment: Thanks Rohit for clearing this doubt.  , how can i update value of id , if my json will be like this from previous response,

Comment: You can see in line no 6 im actually updating ID value from 1 to 2..
You just have to locate ID element using JSON Path (here JSON path for ID is check.id) and update its value ...Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks , Sorry my PC got cranshed before I am completing my query , Here is updated query ,      "how can i update value of id , if my json will be like this from previous response, "      { 
            "test":"rest",
            "check" :[ { 
                       "id":1,
                       "name": "xyz",
                       "status":"updated"
                     }, {}  ]
         }

Comment: Thanks, Sorry my PC got crashed before I am completing my query, Here is updated query, "how can I update the value of "name" in id=1, if "check" is an array of object                                                                                                                                             
        { "test":"rest", "check" :[ { "id":1,"name": "xyz", "status":"updated"},  {"id":"2",                                                                                                "name":"abc" } ] }

Comment: "-- > You have to use json path to locate id as mentioned .. – Rohit 5 mins ago
how I can locate Object in a array , can you guid ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To store entire response:

   - add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which response you want to capture
   - configure it as follows:

     - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
     - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
     - Template: `$1$`
2. To replace `1` with `2` you can go for [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) like `${__strReplace(${response},1,2,)}`. Note that you need to install [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) in order get it.