# How to store entire encrypted response, unencrypt it with POST method and update the response for next rest call using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

1. Run Get method to get the data of the policy - response is encrypted.
2. Run a Post method to decrypt the response from step 1
3. On the response from Step 2 there is the field policyStatus and will be changed to value = 2
4. Encrypt the decrypted payload with changes in the policyStatus. I created a regular expression extractor in step 2 to get the response, but the problem is if I directly parameterized it in this step I wont be able to change the value of policyStatus, is there a way to change the value after extracting without posting it so that I can encrypt it and then post it.

I tried the __strReplace() function but this will be possible if the request is step 4 is not parameterized. see below

Actual Body(Parameterized):
{
  "isEncrypt": true,
  "payload": "{${payload}}"
}

Body(Not Parameterized):
{
  "isEncrypt": true,
  "payload": "{\"policyNumber\":\"\",\"policyStatus\":\"1\",\"ownerName\":\"\",\"exchangeRate\":1,\"product\":{\"productName\":\"",\"category\":\"T\",\"shariaIndicator\":\"",\"currency\":\""},\"billings\":[{\"type\":\"",\"amount\":0,\"currency\":\""},{\"type\":\"",\"paidToDate\":\"2019-07-08\",\"mode\":\"",\"amount\":,\"currency\":\"",\"minimumPayment\":,\"outstandingPeriod\":0,\"paymentSuspend\":}]}"
}

the policyStatus is inside the payload field which comes from the response on step 2.

tried the advice from this --> [How to store entire response and update it for next rest call using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863756/how-to-store-entire-response-and-update-it-for-next-rest-call-using-jmeter)

but this applies in the value of the single field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the Regular Expression Extractor in step 2
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('changedPolicy', vars.get('myVar').replace("\\\"policyStatus\\\":\\\"1\\\"","\\\"policyStatus\\\":\\\"2\\\""))
   ```

   Replace `myVar` with your actual JMeter Variable reference name from the Regular Expression Extractor
3. That's it, the JSR223 PostProcessor will generate `changedPolicy` variable with the `policyStatus` value set to `2`

Demo:

[image]

`vars` keyword used in the Groovy script is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it is used for reading `myVar` variable value and writing the replacement into `changedPolicy` variable. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) to learn more about JMeter API shorthands available for Groovy scripts.

Comment: Thank you, will try this one.